# Oracle SQL get column value associated with max(count())

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query. What results is two coloums, oakid and max(count(rating)). What I want is to have two columns, but instead of actually having the max(count(rating)), I want the rating associated with the max(count(rating)). How can I modify my query to give me this?

```
select oakid, 
  (select max(count(rating)) 
     from climbs, routes 
     where climbs.routename = routes.name 
     and climbs.climberid = oakid group by routes.rating) 
  as skill
 from climbers;
```

For example, if I have ratings "hard, hard, easy, easy, easy, medium", the max(count(rating)) will show "3", since there are 3 "easy" ratings, but I want it to show "easy", not "3".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though you want the [statistical mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28statistics%29) (most frequently occurring) rating for each `oakid` or `climberid`. Oracle has a handy function to do this for us called [`STATS_MODE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions171.htm):

```
SELECT c.climberid AS oakid, STATS_MODE(r.rating) AS skill
FROM climbs c
INNER JOIN routes r ON (c.routename = r.name)
GROUP BY c.climberid;
```

Comment: The way you rewrote the query doesn't work for my database, but the stats_mode was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
select oakid, 
  (select rating
     from climbs, routes 
     where climbs.routename = routes.name 
     and climbs.climberid = oakid 
         group by routes.rating 
         having max(count(rating)) = count(rating)) 
  as skill
 from climbers
```